# disable changing css properties in developer options in browser

Tags: html, css, security, web

my question is that if one html element which has visibility style hidden can be made visibility enable at client side in developer options in browser, it is a security concern. Is there any way to block it.

Comment: No, it is not a security concern. If your HTML contains something you don't want the users to see, don't put it in the HTML.

Comment: for one group of users, I only have to hide one hyperlink. Are you suggesting to make different html pages.

Comment: @maverick the best way to do this is to use PHP, and determine server side what the user will and will not see

Comment: No matter what you do: **Never** rely on your HTML for security. You must secure all request on the server side. Like this is also not relevant if a not permitted users sees a button, as the action will not be fulfilled.

Comment: @Nico  I am using javaEE and updating the html attribute style using javascript based on user profile. But the same can be again reversed in developer options and end users can access the link

Comment: Absolutely anything that you do client side should not have anything to do with security. Everything must be checked server side as you can not trust anything the client passes you. Even if you remove the html client side that isn't securing it, someone could mock up a request for example and still pass data to the server.